# Probability in Poisson distribution.

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

**Q**: The location of trees in a park follows a Poisson distribution with rate $1$ tree per $300$ square meters. Suppose that a parachutist lands in the park at a random location. What is the probability that the nearest tree is more than $4$ meters away from where he lands?

Is this asking me to find $P(\min X_i>4)$ where $X_i$ represent the distance of tree $i$ from the parachutist?

Comment: Thank you @Michael Hardy. I was wrong. I now new it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of points within $4$ meters of him has area $\pi\cdot(\text{4 meters})^2.$

Thus the expected number of trees within that disk is $\dfrac{\pi\cdot 4^2}{300}\approx 0.1675516.$

That number of trees has a Poisson distribution. You're looking for the probability that that number is $0.$

Comment: Is it because of the thinning property that the number of trees within this disk has Poisson distribution, given that the number of trees in the park has Poisson distribution?

Comment: @jeremy909 : I am guessing that either it said "Poisson process" rather than "Poisson distribution" or else it _ought_ to have said that. To say that they are distributed according to a Poisson process means that (1) for every subset of the park whose area is positive the number of trees within that subset, and (2) the numbers of trees in disjoint, i.e. non-overlapping, subsets are independent.